# Text size limit on website

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, apache

I am using a combination of ajax php and sql. I have a local copy of this program and a live sever run by a company, there is a button that posts a comment, on the local copy you can post a comment of any size, but on the live server I have narrowed it down to about 512 bytes once the comment gets larger than that, no error is generated but the comment isn't added, is there any configuration files concerning MySQL databases PHP or javascript that could limit the amount of data that can be parsed?

Comment: Are you passing the data as POST data or (ugh) a query string parameter?

Comment: Wel javascript checks the input, pases it to php file through GET, which check's user info and adds the comment to a database, thanx for the speedy reply

Comment: If you want to pass so much information you should probably be using POST instead of GET to pass it.  There's no reason to gunk up your users' browser cache with urls like "http://www.example.com/addcomment.php?comment=To%20Sherlock%20Holmes%20she%20is%20always%20the%20woman.%20I%20have%20seldom%20heard%20him%20mention%20her%20under%20any%20other%20name"

Comment: This doesn't fill the users browser as the link only gets requested and the php file returns a true (the page never gets reloaded)

Answer (score 1):

Ok there was a get max value paramater in php.ini (under the settings for shino or something like that that was on the live server) that was set to 512 I changed it so now the system can handle 10KB of text for comments

Answer (score 0):

is the action of the form for posting comments GET or POST?

if it's POST: in the php.ini, there's a configuration called `post_max_size` ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)), please take a look at that on your local- and production-server and compare the values.

if it's GET: some browsers limit the querystring to aroudn 2kb, so maybe you exceed this... you should use POST instead.

Comment: It uses GET, I don't think it is the browser limit as when I post on the local copy it works but not on the live server, thanx for the quick reply

Comment: I have set post_max_size to 100MB on the server

Comment: I would probably hold it at the normal 4MB if I were you.  You don't want someone to send you a malicious 100MB string... heck, I wouldn't want someone to be able to send a non-malicious 100MB string and have my server try and parse it!

Comment: the post_max_size is also used for uploading files through php so 100MB is a reasonable limit

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I would probably use the "onSubmit" tag on the form an run a quick javascript validation on the input (a function called from onSubmit="return func(this)" will only transmit if func(this) returns true).  Simply have it call a function, and if the value of the field has a string length and return a little alert window if there are more than 500 characters.  That way you don't necessarily parse or transmit anything you don't have to.

You'll probably want to have a fallback so that someone with javascript disabled can't bypass those limits, but that should work for the majority of your users.

Comment: Yes that would be an easy fix but the system should cater for comments of more than 2000 characters, which the local copy does but the server doesn't

Comment: What do you mean?  The server *should* be able to handle 2000 characters?  I misinterpreted "but on the live server I have narrowed it down to about 512 bytes" as "I remove all but 512 bytes." I think you have something else misconfigured if you're not able to parse more than that.  Sorry I misunderstood.

Comment: no problem, see the live server doesnt add a comment of more than 512 bytes to the database, when you press the button, no sql,php or javascript error is parsed but it doen't get added to the database , where on the local copy(where I installed php apache an mysql myself) I can and have made comments of about 1000-2000 characters, so I was wondering if the server might have a different config file for something like passing text through sql or get or something like that.